# Access Office 365 Table Link ghost reference lingers after link delete

Tags: ms-access

I have two Access database linked together on my desktop, in the same folder, but I keep getting the message:

"(some random path that isn't even on my PC) is not a valid path. Make sure that the path is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides."

I've tried using this line of code in VBA... DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Table". I've also used the Link Table Manager process and same issue.

It just deletes the link, then when I reconnect the link to the correct database, it shows the same message again. I've been at this for 2 days and could really use some help please.

A lot of these issues came up after i set a password on the database I'm linked to. I've since removed the password, but still get asked to enter it every time I open up the database it's linked to.

Comment: I never solved the source of the problem, but did find a work around solution. I had to create a new database, import the queries, forms, modules, etc... one at a time, then re-link all of the tables.

Answer (score 1):

I never solved the source of the problem, but did find a work around solution. I had to create a new database, import the queries, forms, modules, etc... one at a time, then re-link all of the tables. No more ghost link issues.